# Bash Script and Edit CSV

Tags: bash, terminal

Im trying to create a bash file to do the following task

1- I have a file name called "ORDER.CSV" need to make a copy of this file and append the date/time to file name - This I was able to get done

2- Need to edit  a particular field in the new csv file I created above. Column DY and row 2. This have not been able to do. I need to insert date bash script is run in this row. Needs to be in this format DDMMYY

3- then have system upload to SFTP. This I believe I got it figured out as shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Im able to get this step done with below command

```
# Copies order.csv and appends file name date/time


#cp /mypath/SFTP/order.csv /mypath/SFTP/orders.`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`.csv
```

Need help to echo new file name

```
echo "new file name "
```

Need help to edit field under Colum DY Row 2. Need to insert current date inthis format MMDDYYYY

```
awk -v r=2 -v DY=3 -v val=1001 -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}; NR != r; NR == r {$c = val; 
print}'
```

This should connect to SFTP, which it does with out issues.

```
sshpass -p MyPassword sftp -o "Port 232323" 
myusername@mysftpserver.com
```

Need to pass new file that was created and put into SFTP server.

```
put /incoming/neworder/NEWFILEName.csv
```

Thanks

Comment: what is column DY?  Is it the column name (header)?  What does "DY=3" mean?

Comment: Sorry thats the headername. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's what you want to do...

```
echo -e "h1,h2,h3,h4\n1,2,3,4" | 
awk -v r=2 -v c=3 -v v=$(date +"%d%m%y") 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==r{$c=v}1'

h1,h2,h3,h4
1,2,120617,4
```

to find the column index from the column name (not tested)

```
... | awk -v r=2 -v h="DY" -v v=$(date +"%d%m%y") '
         BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
         NR==1 {c=$(NF+1); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==h) {c=i; break}}
         NR==r {$c=v}1'
```

the risk of doing this is the column name may not match, in that case this will add the value as a new column.